# Mysql package mysql-server-5.6 uninstallation error

Tags: mysql

When I am trying to uninstall mysql its giving fallowing ERROR

```
$ apt-get remove --purge mysql*.*
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree
        Reading state information... Done
 E: The package mysql-server-5.6 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it
```

How to reinstalled or uninstall mysql-server-5.6

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: To uninstall Mysql Server use `sudo apt-get remove mysql-server`

Comment: @ThorOdinson you can move this to an answer, to it can get accepted if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Remove MySql completely:

1.Stop the MySql Database Server

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

OR

```
sudo service mysqld stop
```

2.Kill all the MySql related processes

```
sudo killall -9 mysql
sudo killall -9 mysqld
```

3.Remove the MySql files and related dependencies

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

4. Delete Database User

```
sudo deluser mysql
```

5.At last , delete all MySql related directories

```
sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql*
```